# Msi-keyboard light

Tags: keyboard-backlight

I have msi stealth 15M. Sadly the msi dragon center does not work on ubuntu. Hance i cant disable the keyboard lights that drain my battery very fast. Any idea how I can fix this problem?

I tried to install msi-keyboard via "sudo apt-get install msi-keyboard" but there is no application for it.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) . The [msi-keyboard package is contained in *universe* pocket](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=all&keywords=msi-keyboard).

Comment: no, because my laptop does not have a steel series keyboard, only mystic light.

Answer (score 2):

Koromix command line (meestic) worked for me:

https://www.reddit.com/r/MSILaptops/comments/rekliz/msi_stealth_15m_keyboard_backlight_stays_on_all/i1iiddq/?context=3

I'm running Linux Mint on a MSI GL76 (same mystic 1562 keyboard as Stealth 15M) and I had wasted an entire 3 day trying everything I could find on the web, in vain. My keyboard would always remain with a bright blue light on, until I tried meestic.
I'm sooo glad.  Thanks Koromix !

Installation instructions here: https://github.com/Koromix/rygel/tree/master/src/meestic
Binary can be downloaded from: https://koromix.dev/files/meestic/
Repository can be cloned from here: https://github.com/Koromix/rygel  (click on the green "code" button; copy the link and follow these instructions: https://www.technipages.com/how-to-clone-a-git-repository-in-linux)
Open a terminal from the rygel/bin/Fast directory where meestic has been installed and type:
$ ./meestic -m Disabled

Comment: hello mate, iam a bit new in linux could help how to install it ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not own any laptop with RGB backlight, but some googling give the following results:

https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/kgx4lz/our_rainbow_salvation_awaits_open_source_rgb/ →
https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB

**Be careful with application - read read [the warning](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB#warning) first.**

You can install this OpenRGB application using [package from special PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/openrgb) as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/openrgb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openrgb
```

and then check its functionality with your "MSI Mystic Light Sync" capable hardware.

Comment: I really liked this answer tho I am looking ways for my steelseries kb.

Answer (score 1):

I found this script msi-mystic-1563.py in this repo. It works with me gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/issues/2289#note_947399598 I changed the PID to 1562 to match with my model. Have fun